# using Aptana Studio 3 to write Python (version 2.7.6) programs

Tags: python, aptana-studio

I am taking a tutorial about Python programming.  I have just installed Python version 2.7.6 on a PC, followed by installing Aptana Studio 3.

When writing a "Hello World" Python program using Aptana, Aptana tells me, "The interpreter configured does not exist in the filesystem:  C:\Python25\python.exe"

My Python setup is in: C:\Python27\python.exe.

How can I tell Aptana Studio 3 to look for the Python interpreter in C:\Python27 rather than C:\Python25?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferences > pydev > Interpreter - Python

Then set the correct path to the interpreter there